# How can I stop IConnectableObservable.Wait() from swallowing unhandled exceptions?

Tags: c#, exception, .net-core, system.reactive

I have a console application using Rx.NET.

I need to block until an IConnectableObservable has completed, for which I am using `IConnectableObservable.Wait()`.

When an unhandled exception is thrown, it is swallowed and the application hangs. I want the application to crash, and the stack track to be printed to the console.

I do not want to add an `OnError` handler to my `IConnectableObserver` because this loses the original stack trace.

I have tried using the `.Wait()` method on the unpublished observable, but this re-subscribes which causes undesirable behaviour.

I have tried using `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` instead, but this has the same problem.

```
var connectable = myObservable.Publish();

connectable.Subscribe(myObserver1);
connectable.Subscribe(myObserver2);

connectable.Connect();
connectcable.Wait();
```

How can I wait for an IConnectableObservable to complete while retaining typical unhandled exception behaviour?

Comment: I reproduced the issue. It looks like a bug to me. Is it an option to `Wait` the source observable instead of the connectable?

Comment: Glad to know it's not just me. `Wait`ing the source observable is an option, but as mentioned above calling `.Wait()` on the source observable subscribes to the observable again, starting a different result sequence.

Comment: Yeap, you are right. It is strange how adding an `onError` handler changes the behavior of the connectable's awaiter!

Comment: Instead of `connectable.Subscribe(myObserver1);` have you tried `connectable.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine, exn => Console.WriteLine("Handled"));`? The default `OnError` method is to just throw - could be on a context like the Appdomain timer.

Comment: That works, can't believe the solution was as simple as just not rethrowing in the OnError method! If you add that as an answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: I actually wrote up the answer, but though I'd have you confirm before posting. The `Wait` ended up being a red herring. +1 for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some misdirection in the chain of events here.
The error isn't being swallowed - far from it, it's being re-thrown.

The usual suspects are some weird concurrency and scheduling issues, but nobody suspects the `Subscribe` method.

When you call `Subscribe` with something other than your own `IObserver<T>`, you're creating an `AnonymousObserver` with these default actions.

```
new AnonymousObserver<T>(Ignore, Throw, Nop)
```

which is effectively

```
new AnonymousObserver<T>(_ => {}, exn => throw exn, () => {})
```

The default error handler will throw the error on whatever context you're observing on. Yikes. Sometimes it might be the AppDomain timer, or on a pooled thread, and since it can't be handled, your application goes down.

So if we change the sample to provide in a dummy handler,

```
var myObservable = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100)).Take(4).Concat(Observable.Throw(new Exception(), 1L));
var connectable = myObservable.Publish();

connectable.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine, exn => Console.WriteLine("Handled"));
connectable.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine, exn => Console.WriteLine("Handled"));

connectable.Connect();

try
{
    connectable.Wait();
}
catch (Exception)
{
    Console.WriteLine("An error, but I'm safe");
}
```

You can handle the error in the `Wait` like you'd expect to.

Comment: Very interesting! It is actually mentioned in Lee Campbell's e-Book (chapter [Lifetime management - Subscribing](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/03_LifetimeManagement.html#Subscribe)), but I had totally forgotten about it: *"A key point to note is that if you use an overload that does not specify a delegate for the OnError notification, any OnError notifications will be re-thrown as an exception."* This should be in CAPS and **bold**! 

Comment: ALLCAPS and 32 pt font too, haha. The rethrow actually happened on the timer thread in this example and wiped out the application. Scary considering how many people just liberally use `Subscribe` every where.

Comment: Also, I wasted some time because the questions on this tag have trained me to go after the scheduler first. :D

Comment: Scary indeed. I have seen many `Subscribe`s lacking the `OnError` delegate in this site! It is also easy to forget about this gotcha if you are using frequently the [`Do`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/do.html) operator for debugging purposes, because omitting the `OnError` action there has no nasty consequences.

Comment: You mention that the application goes down if the error is thrown on the wrong context. In  the case of my initial problem, the application just hangs indefinitely (left it +5m to test) with no notifications anywhere. Any reason why this might be behaving differently?
Asking mainly for curiosity, as adding a dummy handler like you suggested fixes the issue either way which is great.

Comment: @benji7425 you should probably share all your code so that we can reproduce your observations. Currently the `myObservable`, `myObserver1` and `myObserver2` variables are not defined.